# Habilitar textfield en Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, oracle, apex

Me gustaria habilitar o deshabilitar un campo textfield(textPR) en oracle APEX según el valor de otro textfield(textSEC) de la misma pagina.

Por defecto textPr esta deshabilitado.

Si textSEC tiene valor, textPR debe permanecer deshabilitado, por el contrario si textSEC no tiene valor se podra añadir texto en textPR, es decir, habilitarlo. ¿Como podria hacer esto en una app de oracle APEX?

Muchas gracias ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto con Acciones Dinámicas. A continuación los pasos:

1. Crear una Acción Dinámica. Por ejemplo, cuando el valor del elemento P3_STATUS cambie y sea igual a EJEMPLO, va a habilitar el elemento P3_TEXTFIELD1 y deshabilitar el elemento P3_TEXTFIELD2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Crear una acción para habilitar o inhabilitar el elemento.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si necesitas crear más acciones, lo puedes hacer también. Organizando en que orden se ejecutarían.

Comment: Gracias!! Me sirvió este ejemplo.